# C# Editing ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have my ViewModel, and I have my controller to display from the ViewModel correctly, however I'm not sure how I would make the ViewModel editable, as to send the edited data back to the Model. I only want to edit the OrderArchiveViewModel, not the details

ViewModel;

```
public class OrderArchiveViewModel

    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetailArchive> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderDetailArchive
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller;

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.OrderArchiveViewModel> list = (from o in new TshirtStoreDB().Orders
                            .OrderBy(o => o.OrderDate)
                            .Select(o => new OrderArchiveViewModel()
                            {
                                OrderId = o.OrderId,
                                Address = o.Address,
                                FirstName = o.FirstName,
                                LastName = o.LastName,
                                City = o.City,
                                OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                                PostalCode = o.PostalCode,
                                Total = o.Total,
                                HasBeenShipped = o.HasBeenShipped,
                                Details = (from d in o.OrderDetails
                                           select new OrderDetailArchive
                                           {
                                               Colour = d.Product.Colour,
                                               Quantity = d.Quantity,
                                               Title = d.Product.Title,
                                               UnitPrice = d.UnitPrice
                                           }).ToList()
                            }).ToList()select o).ToList();

        ViewBag.ShippedMessage = list.Where(w => w.HasBeenShipped).Any() ? "Order has been shipped" : "Order is being processed";

        return View(list);
    }
```

Comment: The typical pattern is to create an update action on your controller for this. It would have its own view model where you select the editable fields. Then you need to add an edit button to your grid that links to that action. Same for create, delete. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to make an another two actions.

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

where you will get the `Order` by it's Id, map to `ViewModel` and pass it to the view where you will have textboxes for editing. Create another one Action for accepting post request with updated model:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OrderArchiveViewModel model)
```

When the the edit page is submitted you will have a updated model with the new data, then find your model in database by Id and update the properties.

Comment: I wouldn't call them Index() though - that implies a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Can u send the code of your View to get more clarification?

The already given answer could be done by redirect to a page for editing purpose.

Do you want to show the Editing fields above the Grid?

For this purpose, you can add New ViewModel like

```
public class NewViewModel
{        
    public OrderArchiveViewModel OrderArchiveViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<OrderArchiveViewModel> OrderArchiveViewModelList { get; set; }
}
```

And you can send data using this `NewViewModel` to View containing both editable OrderArchiveViewModel depending on the Id and also the List of OrderArchiveViewModel by assigning the list present in Index() action.